# How to delete folder or file in Rust?

Tags: rust

I am doing a folder mirror, when I delete a file or folder I get the following error:

```bash
     Running `target/debug/back-rust -b /home/michael/Downloads -s /home/michael/Documents/Michael/`
Watching /home/michael/Documents/Michael for changes
thread 'main' panicked at 'called `Result::unwrap()` on an `Err` value: Os { code: 2, kind: NotFound, message: "No such file or directory" }', src/main.rs:115:53
note: run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=1` environment variable to display a backtrace
```

when i tried to delete a folder

This is my code:
utils/remove_file.rs:

```rust
use std::fs;
use std::path::{Path, PathBuf};

pub fn remove_file(source_base_path: PathBuf, from_path: PathBuf, to_directory: PathBuf) {
    let relative_path = from_path.strip_prefix(&source_base_path).unwrap();
    let destination_path = to_directory.join(relative_path);

    if destination_path.is_file() {
        fs::remove_file(&destination_path).unwrap();
    } else if destination_path.is_dir() {
        fs::remove_dir_all(&destination_path).unwrap();
    }
}
```

the from path can be a folder o file, too can be file into folder into folder, but i don't know how to delete correctly

main.rs:

```rust
            if !deleted_files.is_empty() {
                for file_path in deleted_files {
                    remove_file(
                        source_directory.clone(),
                        fs::canonicalize(file_path),
                        backup_directory.clone(),
                    );
                }
            }
```

Comment: Your error says it came from an `.unwrap()` in `src/main.rs`.

Comment: Please provide an MCVE. In particular, what are you passing to `remove_file`? The command output only has two paths in it.

Comment: The message you posted states that the error is in `main.rs`. Why are you showing us `remove_file.rs`? Please provide a [mre].

Comment: unless you're writing for demo purposes, or you're absolutely sure that something can not fail (which is NOT this case), do not use unwrap. And, according to the error, you don't have a file/directory with the name you are giving whatever function. Without the main.rs, we can't help further.

Comment: Thanks for the the good view. Before I make a fs:canonicalize to a delete file. I fix it with the use path::Pathbuf::from...

Answer (score 0):

The problem has because I `canonicalize` a delete file, that this make the error, with make a `path::PathBuf::from(file_path)` the error has be fixed

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).